# Why is the width shrinking for display:table-cell?

Tags: html, css

I've posted a fiddle [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jDyYc/)

i've set the display property of both div's as table-cell. and width of one of the div is set to 24%. but i don't get the result in screen. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting it to be 24% of?

Comment: of the parent container. here it's #content.

Comment: Try setting a fixed pixel width on either `#content` or `#recent_column`

Comment: @robertc nah, i want it be fluidic, can u suggest a different method to show a sidebar through the height of the #content, where the height of content depends on the height of the .container

Answer (score 0):

I don't know gor what reason you set the display of the divs to table-cell. That makes not really sense in your case.

Set the divs "recent-cell" and container to float:left and you will have no problems with the fluid behaviour.